# why can't I create a lazy property accessing a tableView row?

Tags: uitableview, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

I want to create a cell property and access it. I'm creating it *lazy* because it can't be accessed during initialization of the tableView.

I placed it as a property of a my tableViewController subclass, but I'm getting the following error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'

My code:

```
lazy var messageCell : CustomCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 1)) as! CustomCell
```

Yet if I post this exact line without the `lazy` inside a function it would all work fine...

Answer (score 0):

`lazy` variables can only be declared as a member of a class or a struct. Set an `@IBOutlet` to your table. Let's call it `tblView`. Then you can declare a `lazy` instantiated variable like shown below.

```
lazy var cell: CustomCell = {
    return self.tblView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 1)) as! CustomCell
}()
```

Remember, the variable has to be a member of a class or a struct and not being declared inside a function